# Need help mounting device :  mount -t ntfs-3g mount failed: No such device

Tags: windows-7, linux, password-recovery

I'm using ophcrack-vista-livecd-3.4.0.iso on Windows 7 to recover a password. When I tried using the software, I got a message saying "`Tables Found`" along with another message saying "`No partition containing hashes found`".

In root (su: password is 'root'), here is what I have tried so far along with the results...

```
> Fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 750.1 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track/ 91201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device    Boot   Start      End     Blocks       Id     System
/dev/sda1          1         5      40131        de     Unknown
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/sda2   *      6       1735     13891584     7      HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3        1735      182402   1451210752   7      HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sbd: 750.1 GB, 750153674016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk /dev/sbd doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I assumed the partition that operated in Windows that needed to be mounted was `/dev/sda2` so here's what I tried next...

```
> mknod /dev/sda2 b 22 1
mknode: /dev/sda2: File exists
> mkdir /media/ntfs
> mount /dev/sda2 /media/ntfs
mount: mounting /dev/sda2 on /media/ntfs failed: Invalid argument
> mount -o force -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/ntfs
mount: mounting /dev/sda2 on /media/ntfs failed: No such device
```

I tried the same thing using `/dev/sda3` and `dev/sbd` just in case and I got the same results. The only device that is properly mounted is `dev/sda1` which is mounted to `media/sda1`.

Does anybody know what I need to do to properly mount `dev/sda2` so I can get Ophcrack to work?

**edit**

```
>dmesg
    ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf9301000 port 0xf9301300 irq 19
ata6: DUMMY
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 1.2.7-k2
e1000e: Copyright (c) 1999 - 2010 Intel Corporation.
pcnet32: pcnet32.c:v1.35 21.Apr.2008 tsbogend@alpha.franken.de
e100: Intel(R) PRO/100 Network Driver, 3.5.24-k2-NAPI
e100: Copyright(c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation
ThunderLAN driver v1.15a
TLAN: 0 devices installed, PCI: 0 EISA: 0
ns83820.c: National Semiconductor DP83820 10/100/1000 driver.
PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
PPP Deflate Compression module registered
PPP BSD Compression module registered
PPP MPPE Compression module registered
NET: Registered protocol family 24
tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxkqualcomm.com>
dmfe: Davicom DM9xxx net driver, version 1.36.4 (2002-01-17)
windbond-840.c:v1.01-e (2.4 port) Sep-11-2006 Donald Becker <becker@scyld.com>
  http://www.scyld.com/network/drivers.html
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: setting latency timer to 64
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI Host Controller
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: debug port 2
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: irq 16, io mem 0xf9303000
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0:EHCI Host Controller
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xf9302000
ehci_hcd: 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
serio: i8042 KDB port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input0
cpuidle: using governor ladder
cpuidle: using governor menu
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
TCP cubic registered
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
ata4.00: ATAPI: PLDS BD-RE DH-8B2SH, SD11, max UDMA/100
ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata2: SATA link up 2.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
ata3.00: ATAI: PLDS DVD+/-RW DH-16ABS, PD11, max UDMA/100
ata1.00: ATA-8: ST3750528AS, CC46, max UDMA/133
ata1.00: 14615149168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
ata2.00: ATA-8: ST3750528AS, CC46, max UDMA/133
ata2.00: 14615149168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA     ST3750528AS     CC46 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sd 0:0:0:0: [**sda**] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/698 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA     ST3750528AS     CC46 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/698 GiB)
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protocol is off
sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
sd 0:0:0:0: [**sda**] Write protocol is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [**sda**] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
sd 0:0:0:0: [**sda**] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
scsi 2:0:0:0 CD-ROM        PLDS      DVD+-RW DH-16ABS PD11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
scsi 3:0:0:0 CD-ROM        PLDS      DVD+-RE DH-8B2SH SD11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 47x/94x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
 sdb: unknown partition table
 sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
sda: p3 size 2902421504 extends beyond EOD,
sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
enabling native capacity
 sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
sda: p3 size 2902421504 extends beyond EOD, truncated
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Freeing unsused kernel memory: 408k freed
usb1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
Linux agpart interface v0.103
hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
HDA Intel 000:01:00.1: setting latency timer to 64
usb 1-1.4: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input1
generic usb 0003:046D:C52B.0001: input: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0
input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input2
generic usb 0003:046D:C52B.0002: input,hiddev0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input1
generic usb 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input2
usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.3
xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: irq 17, io mem 0xfb300000
xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: Failed to enable MSI-X
xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: failed to allocate MSI entry
usb usb3: No Superspeed endpoint companion for config 1 interface 0 altsetting
0ep 129: using minimum values
xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 3-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03FO pid 0x7511
usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
tg3.c:v3.115 (October 14, 2010)
tg3 0000:04:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
tg3 0000:04:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
tg3 mdio bus: probed
tg3 0000:04:00.0: eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM57788) rev 57780001] (PCI Express) MAC address d4:be:d9:8c:b5:ae
tg3 0000:04:00.0: eth0: attached PHY driver [Broadcom BCM57780] (mii_bus:phy_add r=400:01)
tg3 0000:04:00.0: eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
tg3 0000:04:00.0: eth0: dma_rwctrl [76180000] dma_mask[64-bit]
SB-SFI 0000:05:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
SB-SFI 0000:05:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
usb 2-1.4: new low speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
input: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.0/input/input3
generic-usb 0003:04CA:0027.0004: input: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input0
input: Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input4
generic-usb 0003:04CA:0027.0005: input,hiddev0: USB HID v1.10 Device [Lite-One Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.4/input1
usb 2-1.8: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.8:1.0
input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input5
ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input6
ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access    HP     Photosmart C4700 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
tg3 0000:04:00.0: eth0: Link is down
scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access    Generic- SD/MMC        1.00 PQ: ANSI: 0
sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

**Edit 2** Here are the new commands I tried and their results.

```
>file -s /dev/sda2
sh: file: not found

>cat /proc/filesystems | grep fuse
nodev    fuse
         fuseblk
nodev    fusectl

>strace mount.ntfs-3g
sh: strace: not found
```

Comment: Run `dmesg` ater the `No such device` error to get more information.

Comment: The newest messages are at the end, so work backward from there looking for any sign of ntfs or sda2

Comment: Thanks. I'm editing my post to show everything. I'll try to highlight the sda parts.

Comment: Well, that wasn't very helpful. Here are a some more commands to try to gather more diagnostic information: `file -s /dev/sda2` and `cat /proc/filesystems | grep fuse` and `strace mount.ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/ntfs`

Comment: I just tried all of the commands and posted the results.

Comment: Your live CD is short on troubleshooting tools. Maybe just `mount.ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /media/ntfs -o debug`

Comment: I tried that command, but nothing happened. I then tried my mounting procedures and tried to run Ophcrack, but I got the same results.